# How to perform a join on two files within the same RDD loaded using wholeTextFiles()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am fairly new to spark-scala so please don't mind if this is a beginner question.

I have a directory test which contains two files, input1.txt and input2.txt.
Now, lets say i create a RDD called inputRDD using

```
val inputRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("/home/hduser/test")
```

which includes both the files into the pair RDD (inputRDD).

based on my understanding, inputRDD contains file name as the key and contents as the value
something like this

```
(input1.txt,contents of input1.txt)
(input2.txt,contents of input2.txt)
```

Now, lets say I have to perform a join on both the files this way(which are in the same RDD) based on the first column.

```
contents of input1.txt
----------------------
1 a
1 b
2 c
2 d

contents of input2.txt
----------------------
1 e
2 f
3 g
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Are you expecting more text files in your test directory? If yes, do you want to join them too? If yes, how?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan for now I have only two and I am not quite sure how to perform a join in this case because they are in the same RDD. It would have been direct if they were in different RDDs.

Comment: See my answer below :) I guess thats what you desire

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Thank you :) But, is there a way to do something similar when the file names are not known? because lets say in the real world scenario when there are multiple small sized files, then giving exact file names would get messy!

Comment: updated my answer :) please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first split your content, then do a `reduceByKey` to format your join. Something like below:

```
val outputRDD = inputRDD.mapPartitions(iter => {
  iter.map(path_content => {
    // split string content
    val splittedStr = path_content._2.split(" ")
    // outputs (1, a) (1, b) (2, c)
    (splittedStr(0), splittedStr(1)) 
  })
}).reduceByKey(_ + _) // this outputs (1, abe)
```

Comment: this doesnt give the correct output. It outputs this
`(1,e
2a
1) `
But I understand what you are trying to do. Will work on that

Comment: Then you can debug the split output first. It's probably not split by space. Make sure the split tuple is in the format you want before you do `reduceByKey`

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two files in your `test` directory and if the filenames are known then you can separate the texts of two files into two `rdds` and use `join` as below

```
val rdd1 = inputRDD.filter(tuple => tuple._1.contains("input1.txt"))
  .flatMap(tuple => tuple._2.split("\n"))
  .map(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(array => (array(0), array(1)))

val rdd2 = inputRDD.filter(tuple => tuple._1.contains("input2.txt"))
  .flatMap(tuple => tuple._2.split("\n"))
  .map(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(array => (array(0), array(1)))


rdd1.join(rdd2).foreach(println)
```

You should have output as

```
(2,(c,f))
(2,(d,f))
(1,(a,e))
(1,(b,e))
```

I hope this is what you desire

**Updated**

If there are two files in `test` directory whose names are unknown then you can avoid `wholeTextFile` api and use `textFile` api to read them as separate `rdds` and `join` them as above. But for that you will have to write a function to list the files.

```
import java.io.File

def getListOfFiles(dir: String):List[File] = {
  val d = new File(dir)
  if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
    d.listFiles.filter(_.isFile).toList
  } else {
    List[File]()
  }
}

val fileList = getListOfFiles("/home/hduser/test")

val rdd1 = sc.textFile(fileList(0).getPath)
  .map(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(array => (array(0), array(1)))

val rdd2 = sc.textFile(fileList(1).getPath)
  .map(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(array => (array(0), array(1)))

rdd1.join(rdd2).foreach(println)
```

Comment: there is a limitation to this if number of files/filenames are unknown

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram yes definitely. Please read my answer that I have mentioned the limitation that if the filenames are known. By the way I have just updated my answer.

Comment: oh yeah!. I havent seen your updated answer. but OPS wants to achieve this with `sc.wholeTextFiles` if not it can be possible with above approach also!

Comment: He can combine both solution to get his job done if your expectation is correct @RamGhadiyaram. But lets wait for Rahuls feedback and his further confusions. :)

Comment: yeah Its not my expectation,  he mentioned that he is using `wholetextfiles` in the title as well as question body also.... if he is free to use `textfile` then its okay!

Comment: The answer gets the job done... I was just venturing into the possibilities that I could possibly think of with `wholeTextFiles`. Because i read somewhere that if there are multiple smaller sized files then `sc.wholeTextFiles` can be used.. Similar to a situation where you have outputs from multiple partitions of a mapreduce job and those files have to be fed as input.

Comment: Yeah thats really great that you are trying the possibilities of wholeTextFiles. :) If my answer helped then you can accept it. I guess its not possible for you to upvote right now. :) If you are intending to use wholeTextFiles then you can combine my answer to meet your need and to explore more :)

Comment: @RahulKumar do you still have confusions? if not then please accept and upvote